# MSVC - C++ - Release build failed - linker error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

HI,

If I am trying to build and link my app in Release mode, i got linker error:

> Error 72  error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   MyModels::MT6::MT6(double)"
>   (??0MT6@MyModels@@QAE@N@Z)    C:\Martin\Programing\WoknaTest\WoknaTest\DXForm.obj WoknaTest

In debug mode everything works fine.... what could be possibly wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Ok.. i found problem.. one of my *.h files was incorectly set as C/C++ *.cpp file :/ Even if extension was *.h

Comment: what exactly you did to solve the issue ? @Perry

Answer (score 6):

Judging from the fact that it builds successfully in the debug configuration, my first suggestion would be to check the additional dependencies supplied to the linker.  This setting would be `Additional Dependencies` setting under `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input`.  Make sure this setting matches what is under the debug configuration, assuming there aren't debug-build-specific library names.

Comment: @Perry: Where is MyModels::MT6::MT6 defined then?  It's not under an #ifdef DEBUG or some such, is it?

Comment: No.. it has only #ifndef VOXEL_LOADER_H #define VOXEL_LOADER_H ... <code - not using external libs> #endif

Comment: @Perry: And the .obj / .lib the definition is being compiled into is being passed to the linker when you're building WonkaTest?

Comment: all *.obj files are compiled in /Release dir

Answer (score 3):

I'd check in the Project settings that all the .lib includes and dlls are included in both Release and Debug modes.

The solution to this is probably in the project settings  for linking somewhere (either .lib .dll or path includes) , but I can't really tell you exactly where from the info. you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely version (provided that you didn't manually edit your project settings) is that there is some library referenced by your code and you don't have the release version of your library. Typically, the linker references libraries with "d" suffix for debug and without it for release.

For example: you have a project VectorMath in your solution. The project by default builds a library vectormathd.lib in debug config and vectormath.lib in release. If your dependencies are screwed up and you have never build a release version of vectormath, you'll build your main project in release and it will be looking for vectormath.lib, which you won't have - hence the unresolved external symbol. The solution would be to make sure that all projects are built in release mode, or fix the dependencies to have the VS do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is always a this 2 solutions:

1. Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > General, Link Library Dependencies = Yes
2. Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input, Additional Dependencies, Edit. Check ‘Inherit from parent or project defaults’